# must be configured to display at least 256 colour

Tags: linux, oracle

While installing Oracle 19c Client, I am getting this error.

```
Chencking monitor: must be configured to display at least 256 colors
>>> Could not execute auto check for display colors using command /usr/bin/xdpyinfo. Check if the DISPLAY vairable is set. 
Failed <<<<
Some requirement checks failed. You must fulfill these requirements before continuing with the installation
```

I dont use Putty or mobaxterm. I using Linux's own terminal on virtual machine.

Comment: did you export the display before run the installer ??

Comment: Should i do like that export DISPLAY=myserverip:0.0     Because i run this in virtual machine. I dont try to connect with Putty or other programs.

Comment: that depends. are you running the installer in the normal terminal or are you using xterm ?

Comment: normal linux terminal.

Comment: you should try xterm. check whether or not you have the xterm installed. `whereis xterm`

Comment: can i do this, use just normal terminal? i want to do this like that.

Comment: it won't work. you need a X emulator in your client, like xming , To use Xming, SSH into your laptop with PuTTY, make sure to check "Enable X11 Forwarding" under the Connection > SSH > X11 section.

Comment: i know these. but yestersay i ran the software without these. i logged to server in virtual machine.  Just opened the terminal. and i could ran the software. ( without any other program like putty or xming). But today didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem due to lack of X terminal. As you are running the `runinstaller` on your virtual machine, run the following commands to allow a X terminal session:

Log as root :

```
# allow connections from outside to the x terminal. the option `+` provided access to everyone, even if they aren't on the list (i.e., access control is turned off).
xhost + 
# xterm opens a terminal X session 
xterm
# sudo to your oracle user
su - oracle 
# /path_to_sw/runInstaller
```